# Vertically center Loading DIV with CSS % Based on Screen, Not Page

Tags: html, css

Suppose the CSS for my Please Wait dialog is

```
.loadingProgressDialog {
    width: 400px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid black;
    top: 60%;
    left: 40%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999999999;
    background-color: white;    
}
```

When I display it at the bottom of the page on a laptop, the DIV is out of view at the top. The positioning depends on how far scrolled I am, rather than on a fixed 60% taken from the current visible section size. Is there an easy way to get it based on current screen size without resorting to JS hackery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `.loadingProgressDialog` is screen size based, you can use `position: fixed;` along with [viewport units](https://www.sitepoint.com/css-viewport-units-quick-start/) `vh` and `vw`

```
.loadingProgressDialog {
    width: 400px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid black;
    top: 60vh;
    left: 40vw;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999999999;
    background-color: white;    
}
```